# How to cancel autocomplete in Visual Studio 2015 by pressing "Space"?

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

How to cancel autocomplete in Visual Studio 2015 by pressing "Space"?

Looks like there is no such option.

When I see intellisense auto-complete list and press "Space" VS automatically print highlighted item. I want cancel it. VS 2013 doesn't behave itself like that.

Plus when I press "{" VS 2015 automatically print right "}" I would cancel it too.

Language c#.

If you want fix it vote for https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9319764-visual-studio-2015-cancel-intellisense-autocomple

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Escape key will cancel intellisense and allow you to continue typing anything you want without interferences. Just tried it on VS2013 to confirm.

As to the "{" being closed with a "}", this is usually caused by an extension such as Resharper, MS PowerTools, or similar.

Comment: I better will use VS 2013 =). There are too many bags in VS 2015 (except that). Looks like Microsoft change nothing (fix no one bag) since Preview version.

Comment: any way to cancel this default behavior?  It's absolutely maddening.

Comment: The only way is writing to developers.

Comment: Vote for https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9319764-visual-studio-2015-cancel-intellisense-autocomple

Answer (score 25):

To disable autocomplete you can use:

Edit->IntelliSense->Toggle Completion Mode(Ctrl+Alt+Space)

This will also disable it for all characters.  This suits me but may not be exactly what you are looking for, VS2013 allowed you to select which characters and specifically Space I'm not sure why this was removed.

To Disable brace completion:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Automatic Brace Completion

Comment: There is no IntelliSense in menu "Edit"

Comment: @thedriveee There is on mine.  I am using VS2015 Professional.  Do you have a ".cs" file open in the editor?

Comment: That menu option works for me. I'm using visual studio community 2015.

Comment: this did the trick in 2017, auto complete on space is the most annoying feature ever.  If I wanted to autocomplete i'd hit tab

Answer (score 6):

If you run Resharper, check Resharper > Options.

Under Environment > IntelliSense > Completing Characters.

Uncheck "Complete on space" for the desired language.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to turn off this particular behavior in Visual Studio 2015, while leaving the completion fully functional. However, this works only with some languages. In options:

```
Text Editor -> [your language] -> IntelliSense -> 'Only use Tab or Enter to commmit'
```

Worked for me for the Java Script editor, but there is no equivalent to C# (where I personally don't find this feature as annoying.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Community Edition for Mac :

```
Text Editor -> IntelliSense -> Uncheck 'Complete with Space or Punctuation'
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to just hit escape to exit the autocomplete dropdown, but this works just as good for VS community IMO. If I want the autocomplete, I'll just hit tab.

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist in 2019. Does it exit somewhere else in the options?

Comment: @Hypersapien  it does not exist except under a couple languages.  Best option is disable "Show completion list after a character is typed".  You can still get the completion list by typing Ctrl-Space.