# Stop default Autocomplete behavior when hitting spacebar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ide, settings

**NOTE** The keyword here is "default". I know I can hit escape and the default behavior gets aborted. I don't want to hit the escape key every time the IDE thinks it knows what I want. I didn't have to do this in 2013.

**ADDENDUM 2** It seems I'm still having difficulty communicating what I'm after here. What I want to happen is *nothing* when I press the space bar... I just want a space character to show up on my screen. The only time I want the IDE to actually insert a suggestion is when I hit the tab bar. I hope that's clearer?

This is driving me nuts. 2013 and before allowed you to set completion characters (maybe that was resharper?) But in 2015 I see no way to stop the default behavior of autocomplete.

For example, say I have a class `Foo`, but I don't have the namespace specified already, yet I have a class `FooBar` in one of the specified namespaces, if I type:

```
public void DoSomething(Foo// <-- then a space)
```

...it automatically puts `FooBar`. How the heck do I turn off this behavior?

I should mention that I still want Autocomplete, just on tab though.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Dot before pressing Space.

Comment: Does that change the default behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel autocomplete in Visual Studio 2015 by pressing "Space"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570315/how-to-cancel-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-2015-by-pressing-space)

Comment: No, I don't want to cancel it, I want to change the default behavior.  Cancelling it is easy, just annoying.

Comment: I'm not trying to come up with preventative keystrokes.  I want the default behavior for autocomplete to not autocomplete when I press the space bar.

Comment: You mentioned ReSharper, do you have it installed in VS 2015? If yes, modify this setting (just tried and works): http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Options__Environment__Completing_Characters.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Edit -> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode

From : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx

"You can also change to suggestion mode, in which only the text you type is inserted into the code. For example, if you enter an identifier that is not in the list and press TAB, in completion mode the entry would replace the typed identifier. To toggle between completion mode and suggestion mode, press CTRL+ALT+SPACEBAR or click Edit/IntelliSense/Toggle Completion Mode."

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the most annoying default behaviour I've encountered in ages.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. I literally searched for hours in the options and on the web, for this exact setting that is just not where I was looking.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Toggle Completion Mode" is greyed out for me.

Comment: I am with @youen with wanting to upvote this many many more times!

Comment: I made an account just to upvote this comment. Microsoft, this is the worst default behavior I've ever encountered in professional software. Fix this.

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work on the .aspx side... My CSS constantly thinks I want col-lg-1 when I just want col... Going to kill myself.

Comment: I am blown away how this objectively terrible deafult setting keeps making it's way back in to releases. I must have fixed this three times in the last 5 years, i mean how could you DEFER to the suggestion on the commit keystroke? Like. WHAT?

Answer (score 36):

For all who have the same problem in Visual Studio **Code**, add this line to the User Settings:

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

Comment: OMG FINALLY. Thank you. It just kept completing to the wrong thing if i typed something followed by space too quickly.

Comment: The setting is also accessible in the UI, at least as of August 2021.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It is absolutely maddening when you try to type e.g. `int i` but accidentally press space after `in` and VSCode auto-fills some absurdly verbose class name from a random package and you end up with `InvalidAsyncThreadPoolExecutionContextWithoutCancellationTokenForAbsurdStackOverflowExample i`.

Answer (score 7):

## For those looking for the same thing in VSCode (2022)

`File -> Preferences -> Settings` and search for `Accept Suggestion On Commit Character`.

Make sure this setting is unchecked:
[image: Accept Suggestion On Commit Character]

Answer (score 5):

If you're using *Resharper* and Visual studio 2017, you may need to use a combination of the existing answers to stop getting the autocomplete behaviour when pressing space.  This is too long for a comment so added an answer.

1. Make sure in Visual studio that intellisense Toggle Complete Mode is off/unselected (as noted in other answers). Note: If you turn on the "Text editor" icons in the VS toolbar at the top, you'll see an extra icon that gets highlighted on and off showing you whether intellisense is toggled on or off.
   AND
2. In the resharper dropdown on the toolbar (Resharper > Options...), Go to *IntelliSense > Completing Charactes >* and then *uncheck the "Complete on space" box* for C#.

Now autocomplete doesn't occur when pressing space (can still use tab, etc to autocomplete).

(Related aside: This autocomplete on space is *really* bad if you use VSVim, because you can't by default use the typically vim ESC key to 'get out' of the autocomplete mode. e.g. it's very difficult to even type in the `static` modifier for a variable/function without it changing to some other autocomplete choice.)

Answer (score 3):

change the setting for **Editor: Accept Suggestion On Enter** to `off`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Vs2017 and the setting resets everytime you launch Vs, i created a small script that automatically disables space completion at launch using Visual Commander Extension:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/tuple789/VsCsharpNoCompletionOnSpace)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2019 Pro -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced -> disable "Responsive code completion"

This disables Completion Mode, but doesn't take effect when VS is restarted.
You have to enable & disable it again after each restart, which is worse than using the Toggle Completion Mode menu option.

Since it is in Options, it is probably supposed to be a permanent setting.

Comment: I tested this, it seems to illustrate a bug profile.  Setting this on does nothing.  Setting this off does nothing.  But changing the setting causes visual studio to remember the Edit/Toggle Completion Mode, which it didn't register on startup.

Answer (score 2):

Since Visual Studio is constantly changing, I imagine there will constantly be new answers for this. None of the other answers worked for me on Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. What did work (as of January 2022) was:

> Edit > IntelliSense > Switch between automatic and tab-only
> IntelliSense completion

Alternatively, you can just toggle it with Ctrl+Alt+Space. Hopefully this helps someone else. Also, I've noticed Visual Studio doesn't seem to remember this setting, and I've had to toggle it again the next time I used VS.

Answer (score 1):

For the current version of Visual Studio Code (2020), you can change to suggestion mode by going to **File > Preferences > Settings** and then going to **Extensions > TypeScript** and then checking **TypeScript: Disable Automatic Type Acquisition**. Or, after going to **Settings**, you can search for **"Type Acquisition"** in "Search Settings" and then check **TypeScript: Disable Automatic Type Acquisition**.

Answer (score 1):

[Default IntelliSense completion mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aafn8.png)

Another option for VS19 Enterprise:

> Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced -> Default IntelliSense completion mode -> Dropdown -> Tab-only

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in Visual Studio by going to:

**File** > **Preferences** > **Settings** > toggle "Suggest on Trigger Characters"

I also toggled off "Auto Suggestion on Commit Character" and "Accept Suggestion on Enter"
 - however you may want those settings.

Comment: this appears to be for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion]

In Visual Studio 2022, Edit -> IntelliSense -> Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion.