# Single Letter + Dot Auto Suggestion

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have looked at all the IDE options in Tools.  I cannot find an option to turn off the following occurrence (or I don't understand something).  Every time I type a single letter followed by a dot, I get some sort of suggestion depending on the letter. For instance:

If I type `x.` in a routine, I get ***XAttribute.***.  If I type `y.` I get ***Year.***

I am using VS2017 Community VB.Net. Please tell what am I doing wrong?  I've been looking all over for an answer. This is more for a VS or NET education.

Jerry B

Comment: It should not happen is x and y are declared.

Comment: No sir.  I do not have anything declared as x or y.  It also happens with W. which gives WaitForChangedResult.  It happens with any single letter and a dot.

Comment: It also happens with 2 and 3 letters. If you have declared x or y then pressing dot would show the properties and method of that object.

Comment: When you type one or more letters and press  the dot, Intellisense tries to match an existing variable, class name etc., auto-completes the *object* name and provides a list of properties that belong to this *object*. You have no other reasons to press the *dot* while in the code editor.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.  In an event handler, its a pain when one types an e. to get some  eventargs parameter, such as **e As PaintEventArgs**

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to turn off auto-completion?

Comment: This is a normal behavior with vs. As Jimi stated above, intellisense searches for the name of the typed letters, when a dot is pressed, it ends the search and displays the closest result found.

Comment: If I wanted to turn off Auto-completion, how (for future reference).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop default Autocomplete behavior when hitting spacebar in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301586/stop-default-autocomplete-behavior-when-hitting-spacebar-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Thanks HackSlash, it sure does.  I get around it by termporarily placing a number after the **e** in the sub.  I then use e+number.  Later I reset all the e+number combinations including the original.  A little kludgey but it works.