# Customize intellisense code tab completion in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, code-completion

How can I configure the intellisense in Visual Studio so that it will only auto-complete code when I press tab? I find the intellisense is out of control to where sometimes I can hardly type anything without it throwing code in there. It's not difficult to press tab, so I would really like it to only auto-complete when I press tab. I've been able to do this in other IDE's but it seems like there is no such setting in Visual Studio.

- I am working in Visual Studio 2017 Community, NOT VS Code.
- My OS is Windows.
- I am coding in C# at the moment but I would like to apply this globally to any/all programming languages in the IDE.

I have read something about a json file you can edit to configure these settings. I read in another forum you can access it from Tools >Options but I've seen no such file and I don't know where I would find it in the file explorer.

Comment: Do you mean that you sometimes  lose the intellisense automatic completion when you enter tab?

Comment: Tab is working. I have no problem with tab not working. The problem is that it autocompletes when I press space, enter, comma - I don't want all that.

Comment: Actually, there is no such open option in VS IDE by default to make that enter and space key not working for Automatic completion and only Tab key.  It is designed by that.

Comment: So if your intellisense works in a mess, please try to disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions`. And then close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`,`obj` folder and then restart your project. As a suggestion, you can use [Resharper Extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgOWS1fiP6QIVAv5kCh3S4AovEAAYASAAEgLQkvD_BwE) to disable the space key but not for enter key. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279615/12450747).