# VS 2019 how to stop Intellisense when writing inside a tag

Tags: visual-studio

I have a strange behaviour since few weeks inside Blazor (Serverside) component code.
VS 16.8.3

When I type something inside a tag (eg. something in italian between <p> and </p> ) it comes out an intellisense of I don't know what language (it isn't only html) and when I press space it paste the suggested word

For example if I type "Per" it comes the suggestion of foot**er** and the space pastes that word

Any suggestion how to avoid that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution here
Edit -> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34800837/1169500