# How do I prevent autocomplete on spacebar in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, editor, settings

In Visual Studio Code when a highlighted quick suggestion appears, if I press `SPACE`, the suggestion is accepted and auto-completed.

How do I disable this feature so autocomplete only occurs on `TAB` and `ENTER` (the other default completion keybinds as of 2022.7.16)?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your VS Code settings JSON file.

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

Sourced from [a similiar question about Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301586/stop-default-autocomplete-behavior-when-hitting-spacebar-in-visual-studio-2015) - [source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264485/15109462).