# Disable comment autocompletion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How can I disable Visual Studio 2015 comments' auto completion ?

For example, when I try to comment like this: `/*`, I instantly get `/**/`.

Another example in ASP.NET MVC would be `@*` -> `@**@`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this issue in VS 2015, myself, but it looks like the ESC key will halt the auto complete:

[How to cancel autocomplete in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570315/how-to-cancel-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-2015-by-pressing-space)

Or maybe this, to turn off intellisense?

[Disable Intellisence](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1200596/disable-autocomplete-in-vs2015.html)

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you using Resharper? Or any other extensions?

Comment: No, I am not using any extensions.

Comment: Hm. Something like this, then? 
[Disable Autocomplete](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1200596/disable-autocomplete-in-vs2015.html)